# How to change change images when click button in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am very new in sencha. So i want display , when click button then change images of previous images.

More about picture:
In this picture, when laod file, then red button present, I want to click Ok button change red to green in same place.
[image]

**Here is the my code in Main.js: but unable to change:**

```
 {
        xtype: 'image',
        width:33,            
        height:33,    
        src:'resources/images/online.png'

      },
      {
        xtype: 'button',
        text:'Go Online?',
        cls: 'messagesBtn',
        pressedCls: 'x-button-pressed'
      listeners: {
                tap: function (button, e, eOpts) {

                  //console.log('hello');
                  if (!Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()) {
                      console.log('Connected (' + Ext.device.Connection.getType() + ')');
                      .wishlogbtn
                   {
                   background-image: url('resources/images/Online.png') !important;
                   }

                      }

                else {
                      console.log('Offline');
                      button.setText('Go Offline?');

                    .wishlogbtn
                   {
                   background-image: url('resources/images/Offline.png') !important;
                   }

                              }
                }      

      }
```

**In app.css file:**

```
.messagesBtn {
   background: url(resources/images/online.png) no-repeat;
 } 

 .messagesBtn.x-button-pressing {
     background: url(../images/offline.png) no-repeat;
 }
```

**I got this error on console:**

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Main.js:132
Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'test.view.Main'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'app/view/Main.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Ext.Img.setSrc()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Img-method-setSrc)?

Also as a side note I would suggest putting your logic (listeners) into a controller and your css into your scss file. It will make your application *much* easier to manage over the long haul. There are some really good [videos](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/video/mvc-part-1) sencha has put together.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function **addCls**

try with this:

```
button.addCls('your_cls');
```

or

```
button.el.addCls('your_cls');
```

I don't remember very well.

EDIT:

in Sencha api [addCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-addCls), we can read:

> I have : Step -1 in tollbar as
>
> {xtype:'toolbar',items:[{xtype:'label',html:'Step -1'}]}
>
> There is a button somewhere in mypage and when I am clicking on that
>   button I am trying to apply this class as follows:
>
> **Ext.get("linkid").addCls("inactive");** But its not working at all.
>
> if I am using **applyStyles({})** its working. Where is the problem
>
> Thanks Aswini

No answer for this question...