# style SegmentedButton Sencha

Tags: html, css, sencha-touch

We have a segmented button just below each toolbar. We have styled this button properly. However setting the pressedCls is really difficult. I've tried several forms and ofcourse google. Hopefully somebody can help me out here.

When clicked, the button should have a background color of #007aFF and textcolor: #fff. That's it. How can i do that.

Our css app.css

```
    //SegmentedButtons
.customSegmentedButtonPressedCls{
    color: #fff;
    background: #007aff !important;
}

.button_pressed.x-button-pressed{
color: #148DEA;
background:#148DEA !important; 
}
```

The segmented button part in the App:

```
{
    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
    ui: 'segment',
    allowDepress: false,
    width: '100%',
    id: 'btnLabelSegmented',
    pressedCls: 'button_pressed',
    itemId: 'btnLabelSegmented',
    items: [{
        text: 'All',
        id: 'btnOrderSegmentedAll',
        itemId: 'btnOrderSegmentedAll',
        style: {
            'background-color': '#f8f8f8',
            'color': '#007aff',
            'border-right': '1px solid #007aff',
            'border-left': '1px solid #007aff',
            'border-top': '1px solid #007aff',
            'border-bottom': '1px solid #007aff',
            'font-size': '15px'
        },
        flex: 1,
        pressed: true
    }, {
        text: 'Label 1',
        style: {
            'background-color': '#f8f8f8',
            'color': '#007aff',
            'border-right': '1px solid #007aff',
            'border-top': '1px solid #007aff',
            'border-bottom': '1px solid #007aff',
            'font-size': '15px'
        },
        id: 'btnOrderSegmentedLabel1',
        itemId: 'btnOrderSegmentedLabel1',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Label 2',
        style: {
            'background-color': '#f8f8f8',
            'color': '#007aff',
            'border-right': '1px solid #007aff',
            'border-top': '1px solid #007aff',
            'border-bottom': '1px solid #007aff',
            'font-size': '15px'
        },
        id: 'btnLabelSegmentedLabel2',
        itemId: 'btnLabelSegmentedLabel2',
        flex: 1
    }]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
change background image of different color.

```
.backCls.x-button-pressing{
background: url('../images/back_active.png') !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 65px 65px;
height: 65px;
width: 65px;
}
```

Or concern with this related question

[How to change change images when click button in sencha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419874/how-to-change-change-images-when-click-button-in-sencha)